# Prove that if A and B are denumerable disjoint sets, then $A∪B$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification

This is the statement I am trying to prove:

> *Prove that if A and B are denumerable disjoint sets, then $A∪B$ is denumerable.*

This is my attempt:

> *Since A is denumerable, let $f$ be a bijection $f:Z^+→A$ so $A=\left\{ a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},...\right\} $ and since B is denumerable, let $h$ be a bijection $h:Z^+→B$ so $B=\left\{ b_{1},b_{2},b_{3},...\right\} $. Now $A∪B=\left\{ a_{1},b_{1},a_{2},b_{2},a_{3},b_{3},...\right\} $ and is defined by $g(x)=\left\{ \begin{align}
> & 2k+1, & \text{ if } x=a_k\\
> & 2k, & \text{ if } x=b_k, 
> \end{align} \right.$*

This is where I don't know how to finish the proof. If $g(x)$ was bijective then I could say $A∪B$ is denumerable, but I know that $g(x)$ is not bijective, though it is surjective. Here's a little more about what I know:

I know that if a function is both injective and surjective that it is bijective or if a function has an inverse that it is bijective. I also know by the Cantor-Berstain theorem that if two functions are injective that there is a bijection.

Based on the general info I just said, I don't know how to proceed. Is there additional theorems I should be using and is there something else I am missing? Could someone help with how I should finish this proof and point out is there were any other errors that I made?

Comment: Your function $g$ **is** a bijection between $\Bbb Z^+$ and $A\cup B$; why do you think that it isn’t? (Actually, I now see that it isn’t quite, since $1$ isn’t in its range, but changing $2k+1$ to $2k-1$ would fix that.)

Comment: @Brian Thanks! That makes sense. In terms of a formal proof, is it enough to simple state that $g(x)$ is bijective or should I formally prove that $g(x)$ is bijective?

Comment: That really depends on how knowledgeable (or, if this is for an instructor, how fussy) your audience is. It’s pretty clear that $g$ is injective; for surjectivity it wouldn’t hurt simply to exhibit $g^{-1}$ by pointing out that $n$ is $a_{(n-1)/2}$ if $n$ is odd and $b_{n/2}$ if $n$ is even. I’d actually be inclined to define $\varphi=g^{-1}$ instead: $$\varphi(n)=\begin{cases}f\left(\frac{n-1}2\right),&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\h\left(\frac{n}2\right),&\text{if }n\text{ is even,}\end{cases}$$ so as to take advantage of $f$ and $h$, but that’s a matter of taste as much as anything.

Comment: @Brain Okay. I will prove it just in case. Is it valid to say that since $f$ and $h$ are bijective that it implies that $g$ is bijective too?

Comment: The fact that $f$ and $h$ are bijections ensures that $a_k\ne a_\ell$ when $k\ne\ell$, and similarly for $b_k$ and $b_\ell$, which is most of what’s needed to explain why your $g$ is injective, but it doesn’t directly imply that your $g$ is surjective; for that you’d need to add a little explanation of why every positive integer is in its range (and for that you’ll have to change the definition slightly, as noted in my first comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Find bijections f:A -> 2N, g:B -> 2N + 1.
Show f $\cup$ g:A $\cup$ B -> N is a bijection.